# Question on Crystal Report Latest Version

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a website on windows 2000. We have several report published using crystal enterprise version 8.x. The reports were designed using Crytal Reports Version 8.x.

We want to upgrade the Operating System to windows 2008 which will affect the Crystal Reports. What is the equivalent for Crystal Enterprise 8.x and Crystal Reports 8.x that will run on Windows server 2008. Is Crystal Enterprise Integrated into the latest version Crystal Reports?